# How to change marker size in seaborn.catplot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, google-maps-markers

[image]

So I have this code which generates a plot:

```
g=sns.catplot(data=public, x="age", y="number", col="species", kind="strip",
              jitter=True, order=order,
              palette=palette, alpha=0.5,linewidth=3,height=6, aspect=0.7)
```

How to I change markers size?

`size=20` acts weird and seems to zoom the plot area instead of changing markers size. And i get:

'.conda-envs/py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py:3692: UserWarning: The `size` paramter has been renamed to `height`; please update your code.
warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning'

Comment: What is your definition of weird ? compared to what ? what did you expect ? what did you obtain ?  You should provide some input data (random generated will be fine) + some sample code + screen of graph with size value.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingernest pointed at that you may have older python/seaborn/matplotlib versions. You should provide that too.

Comment: Weird means: it changes the size of the plot area I think, I get a huge plot with little dots on it, instead of large markers. 
I have the last seaborn version.

Answer (score 20):

Use s instead of size. the default s is 5.

Example:

```
sns.catplot(x = "time",
       y = "total_bill",
       s = 20,
       data = tips)
```

[image]

```
sns.catplot(x = "time",
       y = "total_bill",
       s = 1,
       data = tips)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a conflict between the parameter 'size' in `sns.stripplot` and the deprecated 'size' of `sns.catplot`, so when you pass 'size' to the latter, it overrides the 'height' parameter and shows the warning message you saw.

**Workaround**

From looking inside the source code, I've found that 's' is an alias of 'size' in `sns.stripplot`, so the following works as you expected:

```
g=sns.catplot(data=public, x="age", y="number", col="species", kind="strip",
              jitter=True, order=order, s=20,
              palette=palette, alpha=0.5, linewidth=3, height=6, aspect=0.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

According catplot doc https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html the underlying `strip`you are using is documented here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html#seaborn.stripplot

Quoting:

> **size** : float, optional
>
> Diameter of the markers, in points. (Although `plt.scatter` is used to draw the points, the `size` argument here takes a “normal” markersize and not size^2 like `plt.scatter`).

So `size=20` seems to be a perfectly valid parameter to give to catplot. Or any other value that suits your needs.

Copy pasta code with screens from seaborn documentation pages provided above...

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.stripplot(x=tips["total_bill"])

ax = sns.stripplot("day", "total_bill", "smoker", data=tips, palette="Set2", size=20, marker="D", edgecolor="gray",
                   alpha=.25)
```

[image]

with `size=8`
[image]

Comment: You have a different version of seaborn than OP, therefore it works for you.

Comment: It works in sns.stripplot, but not in sns.catplot (kind='strip')